# Remove duplicate keys (and their values) from a dictionary PYTHON

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have this kind of file in a .csv format and i want to remove duplicates key and their values.(VALUES ARE ALL THE SAME!)

```
1: 'value'
2: 'value'
3: 'value'
1: 'value'
1: 'value'
4: 'value'
```

and i want :

```
1: 'value'
2: 'value'
3: 'value'
4: 'value'
```

I wrote this snippet but now i don't know hoe to delete duplicate keys.

```
import csv
with open('cuff2clean.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    chekreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')    
    d={}
    lista=[]
        for row in chekreader:
        d[row[0]]=row[1]
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Dictionaries can not have duplicate keys.

Comment: So you mean change the actual csv file or save the result in a variable or overwrite the existing csv file?

Comment: If you try to create a dictionary like this: `{1: 'value', 2: 'value', 3: 'value', 1: 'value'}` the output will be this `{1: 'value', 2: 'value', 3: 'value'}` because the duplicate `key` will be removed automatically

Comment: Actually as Joe R wrote, Dictionaries can not have duplicate and i did not realize that building the dictionary from the .csv file i lost the duplicates
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to, Python deletes them automatically as Joe R wrote in comment.

Example:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[1] = "value"
>>> a[2] = "value"
>>> a[3] = "value"
>>> a[1] = "value"
>>> a[1] = "value"
>>> a[4] = "value"
>>> a
{1: 'value', 2: 'value', 3: 'value', 4: 'value'}
```

You just need to write it in the file.

Real problem would be if you'd need to have more same keys (use list in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting into dictionary, try to check and insert into that.

```
for row in checkreader:
    if not row[0] in d:
        d[row[0]] = row[1]
```